# How to pass value on next page from checkbox, which i checked?

Tags: php

I have multiple checkbox and want to pass their value on next page when i checked them.
My code is

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="city" id="city" value="Gold" />
         <input type="checkbox" name="city" id="city" value="Platinum" />
         <input type="checkbox" name="city" id="city" value="Silver" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: [PHP Manual: FAQ: PHP and HTML: **How do I create arrays in a HTML <form>?**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    if($_POST) {
        $city = $_POST['card'];
            header("location:target_page.php?card=".$city);
    }
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="card[]" id="card" value="Gold" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="card[]" id="card" value="Platinum" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="card[]" id="card" value="Silver" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: -1. You are aware that `$_POST["card"]` will be an array, right?

Comment: if user want to pass more then i on value the he just get array on target page with explode and substr function

Comment: Yes, but your redirection will fail. Not only that, it will fail regardless of `$city` being an array (You don't die afterwards). `config.php`, where did that come from? Also, if `$city` is an array, the redirection would always try to redirect to target_page.php?card=Array

Answer (score 4):

By defining the name attribute as an array `name="city[]"`

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    print_r($_POST);
    /*
    Array
    (
        [city] => Array
            (
                [0] => Gold
                [1] => Platinum
                [2] => Silver
            )

    )
    */
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Gold" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Platinum" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Silver" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't this produce invalid HTML?

Answer (score 1):

This is not working when both fields have the same name.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="city" id="city" value="Gold" />
         <input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" id="city" value="Platinum" />
         <input type="checkbox" name="cities[]" id="city2" value="Silver" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When you write the fieldname like **cities[]** then you get an array in your PHP-Script.

```
forearch($_POST['cities'] as $city) {
    var_dump($city);
}
```

And an **ID** should be unique.